# shuffle Domino stones in list c#

Tags: c#

I have Domino class

```
public Class Domino(){
   public int SideA{get;set;}
   public int SideB{get;set;}
   public Domino(int sideA,int sideB){
      SideA = sideA;
      SideB = SideB;
}
}
```

and manager class where I create List of it and Shuffle It

```
   public class Manager{
       private List<Domino> _dominoes = new List<Domino>();
       private void CreateDomino(){
       for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
          for(int j=i;j<7;j++){
          _dominoes.Add(new Domino(i,j));
    }
    }
     }

       private void Shuffle(){
           RNGCryptoServiceProvider provider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    int n = _dominoes.Count;
    while (n > 1)
    {
        byte[] box = new byte[1];
        do provider.GetBytes(box);
        while (!(box[0] < n * (Byte.MaxValue / n)));
        int k = (box[0] % n);
        n--;
        T value = _dominoes[k];
       _dominoes[k] = _dominoes[n];
        _dominoes[n] = value;
    }

}
    }


}
```

the shuffle method works fine it randomizes the dominoes list but the problem is that, when I send the first 7 stones to the player class, there are almost every time 4 same stone (same I mean for example 1/2, 1/1,1/4, 1/5 , one of stone number is same as others one) i tried 1000 times and it made 300 times it's quite big number, so how could I shuffle it to decrease it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: Or using linq: `.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())`

Comment: used Fisher yate with random class and the same result

Comment: OrderBy makes worse result

Comment: @user3188370 You say those men(Fisher&Yates) don't know what they say?

Answer (score 1):

The List class is based upon an Array.  As such it accepts the array accessor [].  Instead of shuffling your list (which is somewhat resource intensive) and then iterating through your list, you could create an array of integers from 0 to `_dominoes.Count -1` and randomize that, then just iterate through that array accessing `_dominoes[MyIndexValue]`.  Then you're just randomizing an array of value types (integers) and your list of dominoes never changes.

Comment: I can make that but even when I randomize that I need good shuffle method so it takes different indexes for example if it shuffles like ( 1,3,5,10,4,8...) then it will give the player 4 same stones and I don't want that

Comment: Eser's comment with a link to the Yates shuffle should be an excellent shuffle algorithm.  The Wikipedia page even includes a pencil & paper example to walk you through it.

Answer (score 1):

When you do the shuffle like this:

```
int n = _dominoes.Count;
while (n > 1)
{   ...
    int k = (box[0] % n);
    n--;
    T value = _dominoes[k];
   _dominoes[k] = _dominoes[n];
    _dominoes[n] = value;
}
```

Your pieces towards the beginning of the list can only be swapped with other pieces from the beginning of the list.

E.g. if `n = 2` then `k = box[0] % 2` which can only be either `0` or `1`.

Don't do that - instead, use the entire range for the potential swap candidate:

```
    int k = (box[0] % _dominoes.Count);
```